# LDAP query to show which OU the user is in

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query, nintex-workflow, ou

I am using Nintex LDAP query action and I need to get the OU the user is currently in before moving the user to a different OU. How can I get the user's current OU using LDAP query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Nintex, but the OU can be found in the [distinguishedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx) AD attribute. That attribute contains the name of the account, the OU and the domain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any chance you could provide an example of the LDAP query?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. The query depends on what you are looking for, not what attributes you want returned.

Comment: I did some testing around the distinguishedName and I think I am getting what I need. Thanks!